# How to disable google chrome input fields auto filling in 2020

Tags: google-chrome, input, autofill

How to disable google chrome input fields auto filling in 2020.

I try with:

```
<form autocomplete="off"> 
<input type="text" id="input_name" autocomplete="none"/>
```

Also try: `autocomplete="somethingelse"`

Also I try some old fashion things but with the latest update of Google Chrome I cannot disable auto filling of the input fields.

Do you know any new solution? Please don't give old advice or links of examples if you don't have tested that solution in 2020.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution currently for this Chrome "bug", Google don't want fix it.
Follow https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466 for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be 2 months old but I stumbled upon this autofill issue and it was annoying trying a different approach for 6 days.

This was what worked for me and I hope it helps someone with chrome version >= 83.x.x....

```
<input name="email" type="email" id="emailId" autocomplete="{anything}"/>
<input name="password" type="password" id="passwordId" autocomplete="{something}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js

disableautofill.js does the ways that skip browser's behavior, so it will work.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/disableautofill@2.0.0/dist/disableautofill.min.js"></script>
```

Usage:

```js
 var daf = new disableautofill({
    'form': '#testForm', // Form id
    'fields': [
        '.test-pass',  // password
        '.test-pass2'  // confirm password
    ],
    'debug': true,
    'callback': function() {
        return checkForm(); // Form validator
    }
});

daf.init();
```